# Renew Certification Authority in OPENSSL Verify fails

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, certificate, certificate-authority

I'm in the process of re-emit a ROOT CA (Certification Authority) to fix some  information in its fields, but you can imagine that it could be the same if the root Certificate is near to caducity time.

Of course, before do it in production, I 'm doing this in a test enviroment with a easy command line test (in linux).

I used the very good information I've found here [Certification authority root certificate expiry and renewal](https://serverfault.com/a/308100).

I modify the process to make more similar to my own.

I've create a openssl_root.cnf file. I added some fields like

```
 countryName             = optional 
 organizationName        = optional
 organizationalUnitName  = optional
 localityName            = optional
 stateOrProvinceName     = optional
 telephoneNumber         = optional
 mail                    = optional
 serialNumber            = optional
 commonName              = optional
```

and of course, the parameter to ask (for example)

```
 [ req_distinguished_name ]
 mail                    = Email Address
 mail_max                = 60
 telephoneNumber         = Please submit yor Telf. Number
 telephoneNumber_max     = 13
 ...
```

the section which is more important to me, the extensions

```
 [root_ca]
 # Extensions for a typical CA RAIZ
 # It's a CA certificate
 basicConstraints       = critical, CA:true,  pathlen:1
 subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
 authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid
 keyUsage               = cRLSign, keyCertSign
 subjectAltName         = DNS.1:mycompany.com,
 issuerAltName          = issuer:copy

 # CRLs & OCSP
 crlDistributionPoints  = @root_section
 authorityInfoAccess    = @ocsp_root
 certificatePolicies    = @PCs

 [ root_section ]
 URI.1                  = https://$root_ip/crl/cacrl.crl

 [ ocsp_root ]
 caIssuers;URI.0         = http://$root_ip/certificates/cacert.pem
 OCSP;URI.1              = http://$root_ip/ocsp

 [ PCs ]   #Certifification Policy section
 policyIdentifier        = 1.3.5.8                  #fake OID
 CPS.1                   = http://$ip_local/dpc
 CPS.2                   = http://$ip_local/policy
 userNotice.1            = @notice
```

after than I do the request with this commands

```
 openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
 openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions root_ca -sha384
```

here I fill the fields of the DN with the information..
and so, I sign the root authority with

```
 openssl ca -days 3650 -in ca.csr -keyfile ca.key -selfsign -create_serial -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions root_ca -out ca.pem
```

I have now ca.pem (the certificate) and ca.key (the private key)
now I create a Subordinate Certification Authority

```
 openssl genrsa -out subca1.key 4096
```

obviously, I create a new section in the cnf file for the subordinate authority, name v3_ca

```
openssl req -new -key subca1.key -out subca1.csr -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions v3_ca -sha384
```

fill the fields and sign by

```
 openssl ca -days 3650 -in subca1.csr -keyfile ca.key -cert ca.pem -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions v3_ca -out
```

I have now subca1.pem and subca1.key

If I test it

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem -verbose subca1.pem
subca1.pem: OK
```

Now, I gonna do the new (re-newed) authority..
I *MUST* use the same private key ca.key...

```
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out newca.csr -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions root_ca -sha384
```

I put some information "updated" in the fields when fill the questionary, and sign

```
openssl ca -days 3650 -in newca.csr -keyfile ca.key -selfsign -create_serial -config openssl_root.cnf -extensions root_ca -out newca.pem
```

if I test now

```
 subca1.pem: C = VE, O = empresa 1, OU = Gerencia Criptografia, L = La Urbina, ST = Miranda, telephoneNumber = 02129889977, mail = pki@empresa1.com, serialNumber = J123453450, CN = PSC Subordinado Empresa 1 PRUEBA
 error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I review the public key and is the same, and the *SubjectKeyIdentifier* and *AuthorityKeyIdentifier*

```
openssl x509 -in ca.pem -pubkey -noout
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

openssl x509 -in newca.pem -pubkey -noout
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

is exactly the same...

But it doesn't match!

I guess the trouble maybe is in the *SubjectKeyIdentifier* and *AuthorityKeyIdentifier* but its match if I review both certificates,

Any help? Thanks

Comment: *"I used the very good information I've found here **Certification authority root certificate expiry and renewal**"* - That answer is mostly junk in the areas it matters most for you. About all it does is show you how to run the commands as if you set up a fresh PKI.

Comment: *`subjectAltName = DNS.1:mycompany.com`* under *`[root_ca]`* - this is probably wrong for a CA. I can only *"probably"* because it depends on the rules for your PKI, which can be different from someone else's PKI. But in general, DNS names in the SAN only surface for *End-Entity* certificates (Basic Constraint `CA=false`), not *CA* certificates (Basic Constraint `CA=true`).

Comment: The verify with the new CA might be failing for some other reason, like a problem with the cert - any extra info from adding `-verbose` to your `openssl verify -CAfile newca.pem`? Any other differences between the two CA's when you check over the output of `openssl x509 -noout -text` - do they both have the same serial number?

Comment: Thanks Shane for the answer. The theory says that it doesnt matter if the Distinguished name changes, and by standard isn't a good practice repeat the serial number of the certificate. they have different serial numbers. if I test the command without the "-verbose" fails too.

Comment: Hi @DanielPerez, did you found a solution? I'm stubbling against the exact same issue!